# How to configure theme editor and default encoding in .Rprofile

Tags: r, rstudio, customization, rprofile

I want to configure my .Rprofile in order to :

- Apply the editor theme in RStudio to "Idle fingers"
- Set default encoding for source files to "UTF-8"

I don't want to use RStudio menus to do this

What I tried :

```
library(rstudioapi)
rstudioapi::applyTheme("Idle Fingers")
```

I got this message `Error : RStudio not running`

Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Why is this necessary?  RStudio preserves the theme across restarts.  So just run your code once, and it will continue in the next session.

Comment: Because I am working on an RStudio server in which this type of configuration is not preserved between restarts of RStudio

Comment: I see.  I don't know of any way to change this, but you could save some typing by making a package with a short name and have a function with a short name in it execute your code, e.g. `a::theme()` to run `rstudioapi::applyTheme("Idle Fingers")`.  You don't need the `library(rstudioapi)` call.